# I am looking to add a mat effect to a specific image in GIMP 2.1. Like "border", but without adding to the width of the object. Like a negative value

Tags: gimp

[image][image]Adding a "Border" via "Right click -> Select -> Border and specify the width of the border" doesn't allow adding a Negative value, which would overlay the image.  It only allows you to add width to the image, I'm looking to keep the width of the image and outline the edge with a different color. I have tried using "shrink" but I only need to outline the top and bottom edge.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. I think you will need to add an image (a screenshot, or example) showing what you are actually trying to do.  Also it seems you are not trying to outline the edge, but you are only trying to outline some edges, not all. So an operation that involves only a selection likely won't work.

Comment: I added a screenshot, as suggested.

Comment: Do you want to add the border to the top and bottom of the shield, or all around?

Comment: The top and bottom of the blue bar, specifically.  I must have erased that part from my explanation when I added the screenshot or forgot to add it somehow.

Comment: Ah, I found it, it was in the title of the picture from yesterday

Comment: The program I am using to create this image is great, except where the white bar does that switchback in the middle.  Because of where the points line up, it looks...sloppy and not even.  I'm trying to go for an even width of the white bar so it looks like you took a paint brush and followed the blue line on the top and the bottom.

Comment: I have to be honest with you here, It might just be better to simply recreate this using Adobe Illustrator. It would be simpler in Illustrator. These are just simple shapes. Nothing complex. Photoshop wouldn't be my first choice to use for a graphic like this.

Answer (score 0):

For Gimp 2.10, you were close, but you need a bit of the new Gimp 2.10 magic:

- `Layer > Transparency > Alpha to selection` to get the shape of the object
- `Select > Border` and give twice the required width
- Add a new layer
- Bucket fill the selection (yes, this is too wide)

[image]

- The magic: right click the additional layer in the Layers list and `Composite mode > Clip to backdrop`:

[image]

```
this restricts the additional layer to the initial layer (and makes the very important partially transparent edge pixels keep exactly the required partial transparency, so the edge remains smooth):
```

[image]

If you have more elements in the image, you have to keep the shield and the outline in a group, so that the "Clip to backdrop" only uses the group contents as a backdrop:

[image]